# How to get more .NET version options when creating project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I went to [this page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net452) and downloaded .NET 4.5.2 developer pack installer, then I ran it and it installed it. I think.

[image: dotnet]

But version 4.5.2 does not show up when Im selecting the target framework. I have tried this with other .NET versions too. It shows up on the Individual Components page in the Visual Studio installer.

[image: installer]

Comment: If you want to create a class library targeting v4.x, you need to choose the appropriate template that specifies ".NET Framework". Or even better just go with .NET Standard so you can write a library for multiple frameworks.

Comment: What project are you trying to create? All the options you posted are .NET *Core* versions. You can't use a .NET Core project template and target a .NET Framework runtime

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5.2-4.6.1 [reached End-Of-Life](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/). The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2. All supported Windows OS versions (ie 10 and later) include 4.6.2 or later anyway. There's no reason to target 4.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the legacy .NET Framework, you need to find a template that uses it. For example:

[image: .NET framework]

Comment: If you want to target .NET Framework, it's a good idea to type "framework" into the filter field on the New Project dialogue. That way, you can't accidentally select a .NET Core project template.

Comment: I don't recommend using the .NET Framework templates anymore. Just use the new .NET templates and edit the target framework to a .NET Framework (`net472`, `net48` etc). You'll get the benefit of slim csproj and building with the new .NET SDK.